# Electrical Signals vs Electromagnetic Signals

Tags: patentability

In reference to [the patent US6754472](https://www.google.com/patents/US6754472):

Does the claim of sending electrical signals from the transmitter also encompass electromagnetic signals?

Comment: As a physics guy, not a lawyer, no.  Electricity runs in wires.  Electromagnetic also includes light.  So Morse code is not fiber-optic communications.  No wire means no electrical.  By wire, I mean solid contiguous electrical conductor.  Electrical conductors reflect light, they do a terrible job of transporting it.

Answer (score 1):

IANAL: In my opinion as an electrical engineer I'd say no.  Electromagnetic implies the transmission of energy through a non-conductive or low-conductive medium over some distance.

There is a also the case where energy can be induced from a power source to a power receiver through inductance and/or capacitance over a close distance.

The way I read "electrical" in the patent claims and the drawings is energy that is "conducted" to the load via electrical wiring.

It seems the patent focuses on attached wiring so to me that implies only conductive passing of "electrical" energy.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting fact that might affect the claim interpretation one way or another is that at least three of the prior art patents did involve electromagnetic fields.

US6312380B1 Method and sensor for *wireless* measurement of physiological variables

US5796827A  System and method for *near-field* human-body coupling for encrypted communication with identification cards

US6424820B1 Inductively coupled *wireless* system and method

Answer (score -1):

This particular patent looks to be expired.  So the answer would be no.

Comment: What a patent claim encompasses is independent of whether the patent is still in force. Your pointing out the status of the patent is relevant and useful, but your answer isn't necessarily correct. Also one sentence answers are discouraged. Perhaps if you could edit the answer to address only the patent's expiration state and describe how you determined it, the answer would be better.

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer this 6 year old question. Late answers are encouraged if they add to previous answers.